# Importing large data into sqlite db on android - takes too long. need alternatives

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an sqlite table with my app...but will be needing to add/remove large sets of data as quickly as possible.  I'm open to a lot of options.  Right now, I have about 35,000 lines which I can update in about 15 seconds.  I would prefer something even quicker.  Essentially need just one column to act as my secondary text.

Right now, the user downloads a txt file and then that file gets passed to the below method.

```
public boolean installLanguageFile(String resourceId) {

        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = new DataBaseHelper(getContext()).getWritableDatabase();
        try {

            File mFile = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir() + resourceId);

            InputStream insertsStream = new FileInputStream(mFile);
            BufferedReader insertReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(insertsStream));

            long lengthOfFile = 34504;
            long total = 0;
            int rowId = 1;

            String sql = "UPDATE Story_Data SET text2 = ('?') WHERE _id = ?";
            db.beginTransaction();
            SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);
            while (insertReader.ready()) {
                total += rowId;
                stmt.bindString(1, insertReader.readLine());
                stmt.execute();
                stmt.clearBindings();
                publishProgress("" + (rowId * 100 / lengthOfFile));
                rowId++;
            }

            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            db.endTransaction();

            insertReader.close();

            //mCallback.reloadView();
            return true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are there local changes as well, or is all the data from the server?  If all of it is from the server, the fastest way is just to download a new db file.

Comment: If you can't do that because of other tables with user input but this table is from the server-  dropping this table and recreating it with all inserts is likely to be faster than updating each row.  But that will require you to benchmark and double check.

Comment: Did you try how much faster it is if you don't publish the progress on every iteration? for starters try to remove it completely

Comment: @GabeSechan the changes are from the server.  I have no problem creating/downloading the db.. but my issue is attaching it.  Since the main code queries the "story_data" - for now.. I can just have the method query search story_data and story_data2 and use a preference to switch between the two. if that makes sense.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I'll give that a shot now.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak down to 5 seconds.  I think maybe a spinner would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating all rows in place requires the database to move lots of data around.
If possible, delete all the old rows first, then insert all the new ones.

The fastest way would be to avoid the text file: ship the new data as a database file, [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) the update file to the main database, and then copy the data over in a single statement like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO main.Story_Data(ID, text2) SELECT ID, text2 FROM updateDB.Story_Data;
```

Comment: Thank you.  This worked...and almost instantly.  However, I have one issue...The original table has a few other columns.  All of these stay the same.  Id, chapter, text1, text2 (which is blank).  When I copy over from the new DB which only has text (no id).. it just appends after 34500 instead of going into the actual column next to text1 (I want to keep both text).

Comment: The you have no choice but to update. Alternatively, use two tables that are always joined.

Comment: I'm very close, if you have any suggestions.  the below command works except that all the lines are the same. UPDATE Story_Data set text2 = (SELECT text FROM updateDB.Story_Data)